# How to maintain a daily work process

Tags: java, jsp

I have a table with requests  nothing important, and i have a column with an option, that the admin uses when the request is done

```
<td class="tabContenidoGris">
    <% } %>
    <label>
        <a href=Rechaza.jsp?hecho=<%=resul.getString("idCalendario") %> >Hecho </a>
    </label>
</td>
```

if it has been done it will send some data to Rechaza.jsp and changes its status to done on the database. I have some daily requests so what I was trying to do is when the admin clicks on "done" the row disapears for today, but it needs to be shown in the same request the next day because it is daily.

I get the data of the table with a simple query

```
SELECT * FROM Calendario where ((terminado='progreso')
```

When it's done `terminado` will be equal to `done` so it wont be show in the table anymore. Basically what I need is to hide the request when its done and reshow it the next day or a way to set terminado to "progreso" once per day.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Keep a column of the last date/time when this was checked and compare it.

Comment: This can have two solutions: 1) maintain a single table and show the status based in the last day the process was executed. 2) maintain an additional table and add a new row per process execution with the date and time the process was launched and a result of the process: successful, finished with errors, error during process... and it can contain a column to store the exception. It's up to you how to design the solution based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a **datetime** field in your database that stores when the admin clicks.

In a servlet, you can get the last time that the admin clicked and compare with the actual date, then you can send a boolean variable to determine if the admin has clicked today. You can use the methods

**request.setAttribute("Check")** (parameter) or **request.getSession().setAttribute("check")** (Session)

In the **JSP** you retrieve the boolean var and create a condition to show the links.

```
    <% 
       Boolean adminClick = (Boolean) request.getSession().getAttribute("codigosdecargo");

       if(adminClick == false){
    %>
       <label>
          <a href=Rechaza.jsp?hecho=<%=resul.getString("idCalendario") %> >Hecho </a>
       </label>
    <%}
       else{
    %>
       <label>
          <a href=Rechaza.jsp?hecho=<%=resul.getString("idCalendario") %> > Other option </a>
       </label>

   <%}%>
```